Copy Transform on Bones for each Action?
I'm currently using a Copy Transforms bone constraint on my animations from one armature to another on hand and elbow bones to fix a problem I created when I parented these bones to my armature's spine. Photos to illustrate this are here:
This is how it should look (before parenting hands and elbows to spine):

And this is what it looks like after I parented the hands and elbows to the spine:

I had to parent these to the spine as I'm putting them in unreal engine and require the hands to move with the spine when the character looks up/down. Problem arises when the spine (parent) rotates, it now influences the hands and elbows, breaking the animation.
So what I've done is made a copy of the skeleton BEFORE parenting (so the hands look good) and then used a copy transform on the new skeleton to copy the hands of the old one. Long story short I fixed the hands! But only for the animation I've got open (I set each skeleton to the "slash1" action for instance)
However, this only works on one animation at a time, and I have many, many animations to fix...
My question is, can I just copy transforms, bake that animation to the same action then repeat those steps for every animation I have?
Thanks for your time I really hope this makes sense!
